# laravel 4 - eloquent join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to show a list of users can add how friend with eloquent and Laravel 4.
I try to exclude the same user, and the currently friends

these are the tables/models

```
Users
  id
  first_name
  last_name
  genre
  ...

Friends
  id
  user_id
  friend_id
  status enum('status', array('PENDING', 'FRIENDS', 'DENIED'))
```

With the next code:

```
   return DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.id', 
             'users.first_name', 
             'users.last_name', 
             'users.genre',
             'friends.status')
    ->join('friends', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '<>', 'friends.user_id')
                ->on('users.id', '<>', 'friends.friend_id');
    })
    ->where('friends.status','<>', 'FRIENDS')
    ->get();
```

But not works, also i try this code

```
 return DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('friends', 'users.id', '<>', 'friends.user_id')
        ->select('users.id', 
                 'users.first_name', 
                 'users.last_name', 
                 'users.genre',
                 'friends.status')
        ->whereNotIn( 'users.id', array(Auth::user()->id) )
        ->get();
```

but neither works

Comment: Not work in what sense? do you get an error or no results.
If its not result - maybe you should show original SQL that you wish to translate into Laravel so taht we know where you are going with this.

Comment: i try to get a list of users, excluding the friends

Comment: You work with Eloquent relationships? Do you need to use `DB::table..` or just don't know how to do it with relationships?

Comment: try to `$TableToBeReturned = DB::table('users')...` then `return View::make('yourview' , compact('TableToBeReturned'))`